# What would happen if an SQL Server instance become offline/Inaccessible if you have an Entity Data Model pointing to one of the intance's databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am currently writing an application in VS2010 which will access many different SQL Servers spread out to a couple of servers on our network. This is however a dynamic environment, and the servers might be subject to decommissioning. I have a couple of entity data models which point to custom information-gathering databases in those servers, which will become useless to me when the servers decommission. The problem is that I am worried that if one of these servers decommission, my application would fail because the entity data models won't be able to point to the databases anymore. I cannot go like every 2 weeks to change the source code of the application to meet new server needs, as development time would be wasted.

Are my suspicions right, that my application would fail to work if the data models point to databases which may not exist anymore? Is there a workaround to cater for my needs to "ignore" a connection to a non-existent database?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Are you really asking "If I try to talk to a server and/or database that does not exist, will it fail?".

Comment: Something like that, How will the entity data model behave should it detect that the server not exist anymore to which it is pointing to. Will it make my application crash, or does it do something else?

Comment: I'm not responsible for when a server disappears off our network, but all our servers have a custom made-performance database which I access using entity data models inside 1 application

Comment: It will throw an exception, exactly which depends on the exact reason and what is unavailable. To "handle it", trap the exception.

Comment: guess this situation is easier to resolve if I use ADO.NET w/o linq and entities. Connection strings will be stored in an app.config, iterated through and worked from.

Comment: You just need to wrap each access through your entities with the appropriate exception handling.

Comment: ah. Ok I understand. Thanks. I see what you mean now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an exception when you try to do the first thing which connects to the DB.

The exception will note that the underlying provider failed on open, and will have a `SqlException` as the `InnerException` giving details of that.

Probably the best thing for you to do is to manually create *and open* the connection and pass that to the context in the constructor, using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738714.aspx).